# Custom function to pull through values from a central spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a central spreadsheet which contains a table with yields at a range of dates.

I want a function which will pull through values from this spreadsheet. I have the following code but it runs very slowly, is there a more efficient approach? Note I have only included the code prior to looking up the value in the table (I am comfortable with the looking up formula)

```
Function Yield_Curve(y_date As Date) As Percentage

    Dim appExcel As Application
    
    Dim src As Workbook
    
    Set appExcel = New Application
    
    appExcel.Visible = False
    
    Set src = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("Central Filepath", True, True)

    Yield_Curve = src.Sheets("Worksheet").Lookup(y_date, Col1, Col2)

    src.Close (False)

End Function
```

Comment: This is not a reproducible snippet of code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Is it slow without opening the workbook? This looks to take most of the code necessary time, I think...

Comment: `src.Sheets("Worksheet").Lookup(y_date, Col1, Col2)` - a `Worksheet` does not have a `Lookup` property/method. Also you seem to have a custom `Percentage` class. But regardless, as @FaneDuru points out, the bottleneck is likely opening a new workbook.

Comment: @BigBen I think, `Activesheet.Function` (any worksheet) works as `WorksheetFunction.Function`... I cannot test that now. I am speaking from what I remember about the issue...

Comment: @FaneDuru - I don't believe that to be the case. Seems to be a RTE 438. For example, `? Worksheets(1).Sum(4)`.

Comment: Thank you both - I didn't believe it was possible to pull through values from another spreadsheet without opening first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+value+from+closed+workbook